# Check content of EEPROM during run-time like Visual Studio

Tags: pic, eeprom, mplab, pickit

In Visual Studio, when we try to read memory location, we add breakpoints and run step by step to see what is getting read or written to a memory location.
Is there a similar way, we can do it in MPLAB v8.85 IDE with PICkit3 to read PIC16f685.

Basically, I have a code for this PIC which reads as well as writes data to EEPROM. However, to see what data is getting read or written I am trying to see it work step by step so that I can know what data is read. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Read data, write to variable, examine the variable.

Comment: Where should I see the variable output. I mean we usually some kind of output command that we write in the code, that we can write in the output window to read a variable. Do we have something similar to that in MPLAB too?

Comment: Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: I am using PICkit3 as a debugger. But I dont know how to check EEPROM or any variable when I read data using the debugger. Eg: code line is    factor = eeprom_read(3).It is modified in the later part of the code too. After I program it and then try to read it back using the debugger and check the EEPROM Memory using View-> EEPROM in the menu bar, it shows me as FF only at all locations

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can view the EEPROM during debugging. Here's the warning window in MPLAB:

[image]

And the EEPROM memory view for your current processor:

[image]

Edit:

Given your described symptoms, there are two main possibilities.

1. You are not writing the EEPROM properly- some problem with your code, such as not setting the WREN bit.
2. The debugger is unable to read the EEPROM memory because you have enabled code protection.

Comment: I did refresh it. It reads very fast and gets back to FF. Will adding breakpoints in the code help me?